# JQPlot Basic Chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rendering, jqplot

I need to get numerical data to display as a chart on a webpage, and I've found that JQPlot looks to be one of the easiest JQuery libraries to do this as well as being free. However, despite all my efforts to look at the examples and tutorials on their webpage, I simply cannot get any kind of chart to display on the page. Here is my code for just the basic chart to get started:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Testing plots functions</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQPlot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQPlot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

Here is the start of the page...<br>

<div id="chart1"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Most of this code is taken directly from their examples webpage (http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php), so I don't know why nothing is happening on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these files exist on your computer and in this folder structure?

- JQPlot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js
- JQPlot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js

Edit:

Ensure that you have the base file (jquery.jqplot.min.js) also included too (it can be easy to miss on those pages)

http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js

Comment: Yup. Oddly enough, there's both a min.js and a regular .js formats of each. I don't know if that's relevant, but there ya go. Regardless of which extension is used, the chart still doesn't display.

Comment: I'd also remove the non-minified versions

Comment: The chart displays fine for me on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/tLZuP/).  Included all renders from AWS bucket.

Comment: Ok, checked the link you included Travis, and it worked there for me as well, so it must be something to do with how I'm calling these files. Nathan--just to make sure, you mean make sure I call that script in the HTML header, correct?

Comment: @user1549557 with travis's jsFiddle it's pretty much certain that one or more of the js files aren't getting loaded properly

Comment: @user1549557 are all three files getting loaded properly?

Comment: Natan--THAT was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: np, we've all been there before

Answer (score 2):

Try placing the 'div' component before the Javascript/Jquery code.

There maybe chances that the Jquery is not able to locate the 'div'.

Define the div first and then write the code for the displaying the chart.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the main jqPlot JS before the renderer JS but after the jQuery include, and position the div on the page before you place the script to render the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread is a bit old, consider the following:

Add a container (target) to your web page where you want your plot to show up.  Be sure to give your target a width and a height:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

(Taken from [this page](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html))

This is first impression I had from your code. You haven't defined the  container properly.

Hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Some Additional Points:

1: Make sure you have given the links to all required JS and CSS files in the same order like the jqPlot Website.

2: Check in Firebug Console, sometimes it is helpful.

Hope this helps.

Thanks !