# JQplot barchart example not displaying

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a similar problem as reported on [JQPlot Basic Chart not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657607/jqplot-basic-chart-not-displaying), and despite looking at its suggestions and checking the source code of the example I cant get it work. I copied most of the example code (first example in http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php), then included the javascript links from the source code (view-source:http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php), but nothing is displayed.  Pls see my code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> jqplottest </title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqplot.com/src/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    /* following script code -$(document).ready(function()- is exact copy of original example code*/     
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var s1 = [200, 600, 700, 1000];
        var s2 = [460, -210, 690, 820];
        var s3 = [-260, -440, 320, 200];
        // Can specify a custom tick Array.
        // Ticks should match up one for each y value (category) in the series.
        var ticks = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August'];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2, s3], {
        // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
        // be applied to all series in the chart.
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {fillToZero: true}
            },
        // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
        // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
        // is specified for each series.
        series:[
            {label:'Hotel'},
            {label:'Event Regristration'},
            {label:'Airfare'}
            ],
        // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
        // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
        // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
        // the legend to overflow the container.
        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outsideGrid'
        },
        axes: {
            // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
            // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
            // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
            yaxis: {
            pad: 1.05,
            tickOptions: {formatString: '$%d'}
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chart1" style="width:600px; height:250px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Did you try different browsers? P.S your code works fine on my computer

Answer (score 0):

From the EXACT code that you have posted you are missing the ending  tag before the ending  tab. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I found the problem; the console showed 'Forbidden' when accessing the scriptfiles linked to http://www.jqplot.com/src/. So I downloaded all files instead and it works...